# Find file and print complete path

Tags: javascript, filepath

I have a project folder structure as below:

```
tests
  - features
  - payloads
     - request
        -JSONRequest (create-req.json file is present inside this folder)
        -XMLRequest (sample-req.xml file is present inside this folder)
```

I have to print complete PATH based on finding the create-req.json file

I have created a variable named as requestDataPath which stores path upto 'request' structure. And I am picking my json request based on the value passed as argument. And I am trying to print complete path based on the folder the file is present.

```
let path = require('path');
let requestDataPath = path.resolve('tests/payloads/request/../');

let requestBodyPath = requestDataPath + '/' + 'create' + '-req.json';

console.log('Path is-->' + requestBody);
```

Actual Result: /Users/pranaytgupta/Documents/pranay/api-automation-framework/tests/payloads/request/create-req.json

Expected Result: /Users/pranaytgupta/Documents/pranay/api-automation-framework/tests/payloads/request/JSONRequest/create-req.json

Comment: which folder is your script stored in?

Comment: Inside feature file folder--> step_definition (script is inside this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this from you main directory, try:

```js
  const path = `${__dirname}/tests/payloads/request/JSONRequest/create-req.json`
  console.log('path is -->', path);
```